# How to make a user that runs an interactive script on login and then logout?

Tags: linux, passwd

I have a small elif script that has 4 options. I will need to make a user that has permissions to run just that script on login and when it finishes with the script to log him out.

I am trying to do it trough /etc/passwd like this:
user:x:1003:1003::/home/user:script.sh

When already connected with root and then "su" to user, it executes the script.
The issue is that the user cant connect trough putty and execute the script, which is the goal of what i am trying to do.

Any advise is welcome and appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: can you provide more information? like how you want to execute the putty-like binary or the application and where your `elif` comes into the pictures with all this? More information means a precise solution to your problem.

Comment: "The issue is that the user cant connect..." What happens? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Try a normal user with adduser and then edit two files in his home...

```
# .profile
logout
```

...and...

```
# .bash_logout
clear
```

When this user logs in ( with ssh/PuTTY ) then `.profile` logs him out and `.bash_logout` is executed too. So you can decide to do something at login or logout or twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the full path to `script.sh` in `passwd`. Even if this file is in the $PATH when you `su` to the user, it isn't necessarily in the $PATH in an SSH session. The SSH session might provide an environment that is different in other ways, too.